# Get input from python shell when another window is opened

Tags: python, linux, shell, window, subprocess

I am using **ubuntu** and currently have code in python that launches a picture through a subprocess:

`p1 = subprocess.Popen(["display", "Some-Picture.jpg"])`

after a user scans in a barcode which goes to input

`keyboardIN = input("Scan your barcode to launch the picture: ")`

My problem is that after the picture launches with the subprocess and is displayed, I need the user to be able to scan a different barcode and show a different picture. But I can't do this unless I bring back focus to the python shell (I'm currently launching from IDLE) and have the cursor ready on the input line.

The scanner give a string of something like 'XDSO309G89S' and an enter command.

Is there a way for python to maybe listen in the background for input, or switch focus to the shell window after the picture is displayed (without having to manually refocus the window and input line)? I've looked online but nothing is working for me right now.

Comment: Yes there is, you can, _technically_, listen for input events (using a module like [`evdev`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/trusty/python/python-evdev)) but it's more trouble than it's worth. Why don't you show your picture directly in Python and then you can have a full control over the events on the window displaying the image?

Comment: Oh? How would one do that, through the shell itself?

Comment: I tried using PIL `picture = Image.open('test.jpg')`  and `picture.show()` but this does not leave focus on the shell for input commands after.

Comment: Don't focus on the shell (although you can force it, but I reckon you actually want to show the image on top) - capture the keys on your image window directly. Here's a [simple example](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm), the _Capturing keyboard events_ part.